# Petición Get anidada JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, doctrine, slim

Tengo problemas para mostrar datos que dependen de otros datos y quiero realizar una petición `GET` anidada o algo similar. Tengo una tabla en la que se encuentran los siguientes datos:

[image]

Actualmente tengo definidas dos peticiones `GET`. Una en la que muestra todos los datos de un destino en concreto y otra en la que muestra todos los datos con un peso en concreto. Además, la `API REST` está implementada con `doctrine`y `slim`. En el archivo `routes.php` tengo definida las peticiones `GET` de la siguiente manera:

```
$app->get('/api/v1/providerP/{peso}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $em = getEntityManager();
    $provider = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByPeso($args['peso']);

    return $response->withJson($provider);
});

$app->get('/api/v1/providerD/{destino}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $em = getEntityManager();
    $provider = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByDestino($args['destino']);

    return $response->withJson($provider);
});
```

El `JSON` que recibo al llamar a un destino específico es:

[image: respuesta petición GET destino]

Para llamar a la petición `GET` definida en `php` utilizo la función calcular:

```
function calcular () {

    var peso = document.getElementById('peso').value;

    var destino = document.getElementById('destinoForm').selectedIndex;
    var destino = destino + 1;
    obtenerTransporte(destino,peso);

}
```

Según una de las respuestas debería implementar la función `obtenerTransporte` del siguiente modo. Pero no funciona.

```
function obtenerTransporte (destino, peso) {

    var url = "http://localhost:8000//api/v1/providerD/"+destino;
    //peticion.onreadystatechange = respuestaTransporte(destino);
    var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
    peticion.responseType = "json";

    peticion.onload = function () {

        if (peticion.status >= 200 && peticion.status < 400) {

            var respuesta = filtrar(peticion.response, "peso", peso);

            console.log(respuesta);

        }

    };      

    peticion.open("GET", url, true);
    peticion.send();

}

function filtrar(d, p, v) {
    return d.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj[p] === v;
    });
}
```

La función `filtrar` no está funcionando correctamente. Si introduzco por ejemplo el destino número 4 y el peso número 3, el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

```js
[{
    "idTransporte": 524,
    "idAgencia": "1",
    "nombre": "SEUR",
    "importe": "5.35",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "3",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 576,
    "idAgencia": "1",
    "nombre": "SEUR",
    "importe": "5.69",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "5",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 628,
    "idAgencia": "1",
    "nombre": "SEUR",
    "importe": "7.07",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "10",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 680,
    "idAgencia": "1",
    "nombre": "SEUR",
    "importe": "7.89",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "15",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 732,
    "idAgencia": "1",
    "nombre": "SEUR",
    "importe": "9.33",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "20",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 784,
    "idAgencia": "2",
    "nombre": "INTEGRA2",
    "importe": "5.97",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "3",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 836,
    "idAgencia": "2",
    "nombre": "INTEGRA2",
    "importe": "5.97",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "5",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 888,
    "idAgencia": "2",
    "nombre": "INTEGRA2",
    "importe": "6.82",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "10",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 940,
    "idAgencia": "2",
    "nombre": "INTEGRA2",
    "importe": "9.51",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "15",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 992,
    "idAgencia": "2",
    "nombre": "INTEGRA2",
    "importe": "9.51",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "20",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  }
]
```

Y el resultado correcto sería:

```js
[{
    "idTransporte": 524,
    "idAgencia": "1",
    "nombre": "SEUR",
    "importe": "5.35",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "3",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  },
  {
    "idTransporte": 784,
    "idAgencia": "2",
    "nombre": "INTEGRA2",
    "importe": "5.97",
    "entrega": "",
    "peso": "3",
    "destino": {
      "idDestino": 4,
      "calle": "",
      "numero": "0",
      "poblacion": "",
      "provincia": "ALMERIA",
      "codigo_postal": "0"
    },
    "almacen": {
      "idAlmacen": 1,
      "calle": "Mayor",
      "numero": "3",
      "poblacion": "CÃ¡ceres",
      "provincia": "CACERES",
      "codigo_postal": "10004"
    },
    "usuario": {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "empresa1",
      "password": "empresa123",
      "email": "empresa1@empresa.com",
      "activado": true,
      "administrador": false
    }
  }
]
```

¿Alguna solución?

Comment: No queda clara la pregunta, ¿quieres hacer 2 queries o prefieres hacer una con los dos parámetros? ¿Puedes modificar el código de back-end?

Comment: Podrias añadir la peticion con un peso en concreto.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y añade el código relevante del backend

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo del `JSON` que recibes al llamar a un destino específico? Dependiendo de los datos que obtienes al hacer la consulta, puede que no necesites hacer dos peticiones `GET` sino una sola petición al destino y después filtrar los resultados obtenidos quedándote con los que tienen el peso específico que deseas consultar.

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo del JSON que recibo al llamar al destino 4 @ElChiniNet. ¿Cómo puedo filtrar los resultados quedandome con el peso 3, por ejemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor solución sería modificar la `API REST` para que admitiera una petición de un destino con un peso. Pero si no tienes acceso a la `API`, puedes filtrar los datos que recibes de ella, lo mismo en `JavaScript` que en `php`. Observando la estructura del `JSON` que recibes, podrías crear una función para [filtrar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) el `array` de destinos dependiendo del peso que desees en `JavaScript`:

> He utilizado un `array` de prueba al que le faltan muchas de las propiedades que tiene el original, pero el funcionamiento sería el mismo.

```js
let destinos = [
  {
    idTransporte: 0,
    idAgencia: 1,
    nombre: "Seur",
    importe: 5.35,
    peso: 3
  },
  {
    idTransporte: 1,
    idAgencia: 2,
    nombre: "UPS",
    importe: 3.20,
    peso: 4
  },
  {
    idTransporte: 2,
    idAgencia: 3,
    nombre: "Correos",
    importe: 12.4,
    peso: 4
  },
  {
    idTransporte: 3,
    idAgencia: 4,
    nombre: "ACS",
    importe: 9.32,
    peso: 3
  }
];

let filtrar = (d, p, v) => d.filter(obj => obj[p] === v);

console.log("con peso 3");
console.log(filtrar(destinos, "peso", 3));

console.log("con peso 4");
console.log(filtrar(destinos, "peso", 4));
```

Si no utilizas `ECMAScript 2015`, la función quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
function filtrar (d, p, v) {
    return d.filter(function (obj) {
        return obj[p] === v;
    });
}
```

El trabajo de filtar los resultados también lo podrías hacer en el servidor con `php` después de llamar al método `findByDestino`. Suponiendo que lo que recibes de este método sea un `array`, usando [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) podrías quedarte con los datos que te intersan:

```
 $app->get('/api/v1/providerD/{destino}/{peso}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

    $em = getEntityManager();
    $destino = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByDestino($args['destino']);
    $peso = $args['peso'];

    $provider_filtrado = array_filter($destino, function ($dato) use ($peso) {
        return $dato->peso == $peso;    
    });

    return $response->withJson($provider_filtrado);

});
```

**EDICIÓN:**

Para que entiendas cómo implementarlo, te situaré un ejemplo práctico funcionando, el cual utiliza [el siguiente fichero json](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos) de [typicode](https://github.com/typicode). Una vez leído el `JSON`, utilizaré la anterior función para filtrar los resultados por el parámetro que quiera, en este caso los filtraré tomando en cuenta el `id` de álbum (`albumId`):

```js
// Función de obtener un album
function obtenerAlbum(numero) {

  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos";

  var peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  peticion.responseType = "json";

  peticion.onload = function() {

    if (peticion.status >= 200 && peticion.status < 400) {

      // Al recibir el JSON llamo a la función creada
      // filtrando los resultados por el parámetro albumId
      // en tu caso esta función sería algo como:
      // var destinoPeso = filtrar(peticion.response, "peso", numero);

      var albumes = filtrar(peticion.response, "albumId", numero);

      console.log(albumes);

    }

  };

  peticion.open("GET", url, true);

  peticion.send();

}

// Función de filtrar
function filtrar(d, p, v) {
  return d.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj[p] === v;
  });
}

// Llamar a la función que lee el `JSON`
// Enviándole 3 como parámetro, en este caso al leer
// el JSON filtrará los resultados tomando en cuenta este número
obtenerAlbum(3);
```

Comment: Esa no es la solución que busco. Si puedo modificar la API REST pero no sé como. Podría modificar el archivo `routes.php` y añadirle a la petición: `get('/api/v1/providerP/{destino}/{peso}` ? @ElChiniNet

Comment: Si no deseas filtrar con `JavaScript` no queda más solución que modificar la `API` (por ahora no el fichero `routes.php`). A lo que me refiero es que modifiques la clase `Transporte` para que aparte de tener métodos como `findByPeso` y `findByDestino` tenga uno que sea `findByPesoDestino`. Lamentablemente los datos que aportas no son suficientes para resolver lo que deseas hacer, debes situar el código de tu `API REST` y crear una pregunta respectiva a añadir un nuevo método y eliminar las etiquetas de `JavaScript` y `Ajax` ya que el cambio que deseas hacer está del lado del servidor.

Comment: los métodos `findByPeso` y `findByDestino` son de `Doctrine`. La clase `Transporte` está formada por los atributos que se ven en la imagen y por los métodos `set`y `get` de cada atributo. Podría filtrar con `Javascript` pero no entiendo la respuesta que me has dado al respecto.

Comment: Los métodos `findByPeso` y `findByDestino` _están creados_ en una clase de usando `Doctrine` (no pertenecen a `Doctrine` de por sí), debes tener un fichero `php` en algún sitio con todo el código relativo a esta parte. Si en realidad sí puedes filtrar con `JavaScript` y lo que te sucede es que no entiendes la respuesta, ahora añado más informacion a la misma.

Comment: No sé dónde puede estar ese fichero php. Pero yo no lo he definido. No me importa tener que filtrar con Javascript. Voy a editar la pregunta para añadir código de la manera en la que trabajo con Javascript, a ver si así podrías ayudarme. @ElChiniNet

Comment: tras realizar los cambios que me has comentado sigo sin tener la respuesta filtrada por el peso. Añado más código para que veas lo que estoy probando

Comment: @Lara, esta línea var peso = `document.getElementById('peso');` te devuelve un objeto `Element` no un número. Ten en cuenta también que el peso en tu `JSON` es una cadena.

Comment: Entonces debería utilizar `document.getElementById('peso').value`?

Comment: @Lara Si el elemento es un elemento de formulario podrías acceder a su valor de esa forma. Podemos seguir en un chat para no llenar los comentarios.

Comment: Hablame por un chat, no sé como funciona @ElChiniNet

Comment: @Lara, no sé si ya has resuelto tu problema porque veo que has marcado mi respuesta como correcta. Pero de no ser así, [podemos continuar en un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77119/discussion-between-elchininet-and-lara) y te puedo ayudar a detectar el error en el código.

Comment: conseguí solucionarlo desde la parte del servidor en php.

Comment: Me alegro @Lara, un saludo entoces ;)